# Capturing String Right Before Comma in Regex

Tags: regex, capture

I am writing some raw Regex code and testing them on online testers. I want to capture a list of strings right
before a comma. Specifically, I want to capture up to 3 strings right before a comma. Ex.

```
string string string,
```

I want to capture "string string string" (including spaces).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use something like this if your string only ends with a comma:

```
(.*?),
```

If your string *contains* a comma, this should work:

```
(.*),
```

The `?` makes the first pattern's capturing group as non-greedy as possible. Removing it makes the capturing group greedy.

Comment: Can you explain? Why use "." instead of ^\w or [A-Z]?    ?

Comment: `.` matches any character. If you want to restrict your dictionary, use something else.

Answer (score 17):

The safest way to capture the characters before the comma is: `^([^,]*)`

Explanation:

```
^        Start of string
(        Start of capture group
[^,]*    Any number of any non-comma characters
)        End of capture group
```

Comment: This is the correct solution in case the comma is optional.

Comment: Pure gold. Works perfectly with an optional comma

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^,]+
```

Start at beginning of string, get everything that is not comma.